# PHP loading twice on all browsers, and it's not a missing image

Tags: php, mysql

I have been going nuts trying to figure out why my PHP pages load twice. A lot of people have experienced it, and although some people find out  a solution, many havn't. I have a clue that may help more people unravel this.

I only noticed it when MySQL insert statements inserted 2 entries. When I first discovered it, I thought it was MySQL, but the inserts have different quote numbers which were generated by PHP. So it *must* have been PHP and not MySQL causing this doubling effect. Sometimes it was more than doubled.

I researched heavily, and most people had these solutions:

- turn on output buffering, and start it, then flush it before and after code
- you have a missing img src somewhere. Check there are no 404's on the page, be it styles, js, favicon, css images, or img tags.
- your code has a loop, check your coding
- as a workaround, use a session force the insert into only firing once. So start a session, do the insert, then delete the session. Restart the session on the following page so it can be inserted again later if needed.

But none of these helped.

Despite that PHP would load twice, a JavaScript alert would load once. So I decided that the only way around this issue would be a jQuery post, with a bunch of variables shooting through. Not even this worked - the PHP page it posted to had *no* HTML, and a small number of includes that needed to be present for the database connection.

So I thought, as a non-elegant but last resort solution, that I would have to make it only insert if it wasn't within 5 seconds of the last entry and same IP `($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])`

When doing this I noticed that it recorded two different IP addresses! So it inserted twice, same timedate stamp, but different IP address. One was mine, one wasn't. There was a remote IP address somehow in there.

I thought my security software must be going a bit too far telling other servers information about my machine, so I ditched my Comodo software, and installed Avast. Removing comodo didn't fix it. I did a scan using Avast, nothing showed up

I looked through my software (Widows 7, 32 bit), there isn't much there. Nothing dodgy, no games, and I havn't been going to smutty websites.

So U looked to my router (dlink dir 615) to block the outgoing IP - can't, or at least, I don't know how to. I looked around in Avast to do this as well, but can't find this option anywhere. Maybe I should re-install Comodo and see what options it has

Still stumped, but at least I made some ground.

Advice very welcome!

Comment: What is your question? This is not a discussion board.

Comment: Very strange. Can you show a live link maybe? Can you show both IPs? I know it's not nice to do that on a public forum, but it's pretty pertinent to the issue, so...

Comment: Do you have Google adWords/adSense/Analytic or other kind of script running on your page?

Comment: Have you tried disabling all 3rd party toolbars and such - does it happen from several different browsers?

Comment: @Dutchie432: he said "loadings twice on all browsers" in the title. Do you believe it could be a flash content (updated plugins or not)?

Comment: Do you actually post to a controller page or you post to another page that display the informations right afteward?

Comment: @Doug Keep your questions short and to the point; nobody wants to read a wall of text when a single paragraph and a bulleted list of what you've already tried would suffice.

Comment: I did not see that. My Apologies.

Comment: @Dutchie432: I didn't meant to be rude. Sorry if you believe it was.

Comment: @zzzzBov - its still ongoing, any advice on a solution would be gr8

Comment: @Pekka - I can't really show both, but one of the offending extra IP is 207.138.120.141 to 207.138.120.135

Comment: @cybrix - no i don't have google stuff going on

Comment: @Dutchie432 - yes, in all browsers.

Comment: @Cyrix - no, no flash used at all. No html even.

Comment: @Cyrix - tis one the one page, although i tried both.

Comment: @meagar - a lot of people struggle with this issue. The more details about what i have and havn't tried is surely useful?

Comment: @Doug Up to a point. Stack Overflow is primarily a reference, not a forum, and overly verbose questions hinder people in quickly finding what they're looking for.

Comment: okay, no worries. ill keep that in mind next time. tis my fav find-a-solution site :)

Comment: @Doug - sometimes the details make the difference. It important for the OP to show they've at least thought things through, have done their homework, and for them to share any details they might have come across, what they've tried, or anything that they feel might be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I once also noticed double page loading, after some research it turned out that Google something was following every entered url (some kind of toolbar in IE). Try running on a different browser, without any search engines addons.

Comment: its occuring in all browsers. IE, chrome, firefox

Answer (score 0):

We also once had a similar problem. Turned out to be the [ZFDebug](http://code.google.com/p/zfdebug/) toolbar we used in the development configuration.

Comment: i wish it were that for me :P

Answer (score 0):

If a request causes a database insert, you should be using a POST request and protecting it with a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce).

Comment: hmmmm never heard of that! ill check it out